# change fontfamily for output cells in jupyterlab

Tags: jupyter-lab

I would like to change the default fontFamily for all cells in jupyterlab. I was able to edit the configuration in Advanced Settings Editor for code, markdown and raw cells. But the output cells still use the default SourceCodePro font. Is there a way to change that too?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this feature is not implemented yet. See here: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5764

I got around this by first installing the extension [jupyterlab-fonts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@deathbeds/jupyterlab-fonts) and then changing the `--jp-code-font-family` parameter in the file `~/.jupyter/lab/user-settings/@deathbeds/jupyterlab-fonts/fonts.jupyterlab-settings` to this:

```
    {
        // Fonts
        // @deathbeds/jupyterlab-fonts:fonts
        // Settings for JupyterLab Fonts
        // *********************************

        // Global Styles
        // JSS-compatible JSON applied to the Global scope
        "styles": {
          ":root": {
            "--jp-code-font-family": "monospace"
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the jupyterlab open `settings` > `Theme`, on the `overides` change `code-font-family`

```json
{
  "overrides": {
        "code-font-family": "monospace",
        "code-font-size": "13px"
    }
}
```